# Faded commands and variables in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode when I indent some commands or variables correctly, they got faded. Can anyone tell me why this happens (is it really connected with indentation?) and how I can get rid of this annoying issue?

Faded lines in the case of correct indentation but not always!

[image: 1]

In the wrong indentation, everything seems correct

[image: 2]

Output which is correct

[image: 3]

Comment: Normaly they fade when code is not reachable anymore. Do you have an infinite loop introduced by your function call?

Comment: Thanks for helping. No, there is not a loop in the called function.

Comment: I suppose restarting did not help?

Comment: Unfortunately does not solve the problem. Also, when I use "inspect editor token and scopes" nothing unusual and different from other "print" commands is observed.

Comment: what does the tooltip say when you hover over the faded line

Comment: semantic scopes are not shown in the `Inspect dialog`

Comment: It says "code is unreachable" and "There is no solution available". But everything works properly and the output is correct. Then what does the message mean?

Comment: then you should create an issue at PyLance repo that it makes a mistake, you are the second person with this problem

Answer (score 0):

I have opened an issue in Pylance and here is the discussion, cause, and solution:

https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3240
(Unreasonable faded lines #3240)

another useful link could be:

https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3195